# Conformal mapping for region between a square and a circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I was wondering if anyone knew a mapping that would take the region between a square of length 4 and a unit circle, and map it into the region between two circles. It would be great if the mapping is conformal, but if not that would still be awesome.

Thanks!
Kayvan

Comment: got a diagram? Maybe post on photobucket or imgur and post link

Comment: You probably mean to map it onto the region between two circles? The conformal mapping between those domains is most likely not explicitly computable, if you just want a homeomorphism it is easy to write it down in polar coordinates, just make it piecewise linear on each ray.

Comment: There is no conformal mapping between a smooth curve and a curve with corners like the boundary of a square - by the definition of "conformal".

Comment: Take all [superellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) of the form $|x|^a+|y|^a=1$, with $a\ge2$, which cover the area between the unit circle and the unit square, and map each of them to the concentric circles situated between the other two circles.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The map is defined on a region *between* those curves, so it can be conformal there.

Comment: @Lucian That's not good, all superellipses meet at $(1,0)$. The region the OP asks about is an open doubly-connected domain.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you guys for taking the time and responding to my question. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Lucian, Thank you for your response again. I am trying to determine a representative complex function that would map a circle into a superellipse. I appreciate it if you can share with me what you might find also. Thanks!